# How to get info about file compression using ImageIO?

Tags: java, image-processing, compression, tiff

I have a TIFF file and I'd like to know which compression it used - is there a way to achieve it using ImageIO? I unsuccessfully tried to get this info from `IIOMetadata` object. I initially create a `BufferedImage` from this file, process it and then try to save it with the same compression as original but with different name.

Comment: Do you really need that saved file or do you save it just for getting the information? If you only need the info saving is a bad idea as loading and saving may loose data (e.g. the multi-page property of tiff or other options Java does not fully support). You you need file-info I would not use ImageIO at all - parse the file directly (or use a library that does this).

Comment: I really need to process it and then save it - usually in few parts and I want them persisted in with the same compression type as original one.

Comment: You can use `tiffdump YourImage.tif | grep Compression` then look up TIFF tag 259 to interpret the values.

Comment: Or you could use `identify -verbose YourImage.tif | grep Compression` which is part of **ImageMagick** and is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. There is a Java port called `im4java`.

Comment: *" I unsuccessfully tried to get this info from `IIOMetadata` object."* Can you show the code the code you tried? It should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the ImageIO API the following code will give you the compression (in a human-readable way):

```
ImageReader reader = ...;

IIOMetadata metadata = reader.getImageMetadata(0); // 0, first image
IIOMetadataNode root = (IIOMetadataNode) metadata.getAsTree(IIOMetadataFormatImpl.standardMetadataFormatName);
IIOMetadataNode compression = (IIOMetadataNode) root.getElementsByTagName("CompressionTypeName").item(0);
String compressionName = compression.getAttribute("value");

System.out.printf("Compression: %s", compressionName);
```

Note that this compression name may not always match the compression type names supported by the plugin's `ImageWriteParam` (though it often does). The above will work for all plugins that supports the [standard or "plug-in neutral" metadata format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/standard_metadata.html) (most do).

In any case, a safer option if you want to keep the compression, is to use the `COPY_FROM_METADATA` compression mode in the `ImageWriteParam` (this is the default, so you don't need to specify it), and pass the entire `metadata` object to the write method (remember to pass it as image metadata and not stream metadata). This will work regardless of the metadata formats supported, as long as the reader and writer understands the same format.

The easiest way to achieve this, is probably to read using the `ImageReader.readAll(..)` method like this:

```
IIOImage iioimg = reader.readAll(0, readParam);  // image AND metadata in one go

RenderedImage image = iioimg.getRenderedImage(); // normally a BufferedImage
// ... image manipulation   
iioimg.setRenderedImage(modifiedImage);          // in case the reference changed

writer.write(null, iioimg, writeParam);          // will preserve compression by default
```

Small caveat: Some plugins have readers that reads more compressions than their corresponding writer can write. E.g. For TIFF, the reader might be able to read the now deprecated "Old style JPEG" compression, even though the writer only supports writing in the new "JPEG" compression.